# Determine which function is called by a generic function

Tags: r

I would like to know how to quickly find the specific function called by a generic function for a specific object. Example :

```
library(spatial)
data(redwood)
K <- Kest(redwood)
plot(K)
```

This is not an usual plot, it's a plot build for a `Kest()` object. So to investigate in order to find the function used, I do :

```
class(K)
```

I get

> "fv"         "data.frame"

I guess it is plot.fv

```
?plot.fv
```

Yey ! But I'm sure there a more efficient way than guessing. Anyone ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find all of the corresponding generic functions for an S3 class using methods(). So in your case:

```
methods(class=fv)
```

Comment: @eytan: The function `methods` is actually in the `utils` package, not the methods package.

Comment: Marek's answer is really what I was looking for, but I like the simplicity and the elegance of your proposition, even if it require some manual digging.

Answer (score 1):

It is clear described in help to `UseMethod`.

> When a function calling `UseMethod("fun")` is applied to an object with class attribute `c("first", "second")`, the system searches for a function called `fun.first` and, if it finds it, applies it to the object. If no such function is found a function called `fun.second` is tried. If no class name produces a suitable function, the function `fun.default` is used, if it exists, or an error results.

So if you looking for proper function you need to check all posibilities, eg.:

```
fun_seeker <- function(obj,fun) {
  funs_to_check <- paste(fun,c(class(obj),"default"),sep=".")
  funs_exists <- funs_to_check %in% methods(fun)
  if (any(funs_exists)) funs_to_check[funs_exists][1] else stop("No applicable method")
}
fun_seeker(matrix(rnorm(100),10),"plot")
fun_seeker(matrix(rnorm(100),10),"summary")
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case we are dealing with an S3 class.  (This is the older, simpler object oriented style.)  This means that when you type `plot(K)` for an object with class `"fv" "data.frame"`, R does the following:

It looks through the search path to find a function named `plot`.  Type `search()` to see where R looks.  Assuming you haven't done something silly like defining your own plot function, it should find the version in the `graphics` package.

This function has some special logic for dealing with an input where `x` is a function, then calls `UseMethod`.

`UseMethod` looks on the serach path for a function named `plot.fv`, and calls it if it finds it.

Failing that, it looks for `plot.data.frame`.

Failing that, it looks for `plot.default`.

If that couldn't be found an error would have been thrown.  (Though `plot.default` exists in the graphics package, so you'd have to try quite hard to get an error here.)