# R: Obtaining the formal arguments of a function when applied to a specific object

Tags: r, function, methods, functional-programming, arguments

Suppose I have a function f(x) applied to a data object x. I need to know whether f has a certain argument, a 'na.rm' argument to be precise. I could find out by calling names(formals(f)), but f, being a completely general function, could have multiple methods (S3 or S4 etc.), so calling names(formals(f)) might give me the wrong list of arguments. I need to call something like names(formals(f(x))) to get the arguments of f when applied to x. I give a small illustration:

```
    # x is an integer vector, let f be the mean  
    > x <-1:10 
    > class(x)
    [1] "integer"

    # The mean has lots of methods, so I can't check the arguments of mean(x)
    > names(formals(mean))
    [1] "x"   "..."

    > getFunction("mean")
    function (x, ...) 
    UseMethod("mean")
    <bytecode: 0x0000000017535928>
    <environment: namespace:base>

    # This also gives an error, because mean.integer does not exist 
    > names(formals(getS3method("mean",class(x))))
    Error in getS3method("mean", class(x)) : 
      S3 method 'mean.integer' not found

    # Through researching I found out that the mean method actually 
    # applied to x is mean.default, so what I am actually looking for is:
    > names(formals(mean.default))
    [1] "x"     "trim"  "na.rm" "..."  

    # Aha, there is the 'na.rm' argument I was looking for, but the question remains: 
    # How can I find the arguments of some function f applied to some object x?
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1785737/determine-which-function-is-called-by-a-generic-function

Comment: `findMethod` defined in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42738851/r-how-to-find-what-s3-method-will-be-called-on-an-object can be used to determine which method will be called from an S3 generic.

Comment: Thank you! The first post by MrFlick brought me closer to what I am looking for. I now created a function that approximately does what I am looking for:

Comment: argsfx <- function(f = "var", x = 1:100, arg = "na.rm") {
  m = suppressWarnings(try(as.character(methods(f)), silent = TRUE))
  if (length(m) && !inherits(m,"try-error")) {
    funs_to_check <- paste0(f,".",c(class(x),"default"))
    funs_exists <- funs_to_check %in% m
    if (any(funs_exists)) {
      res = any(names(formals(args(funs_to_check[funs_exists][1]))) == arg)
    } else {
      res = any(names(formals(args(f))) == arg)
    }
  } else {
    res = any(names(formals(args(f))) == arg)
  }
  return(res)
}

Comment: Another helpful post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25978301/how-to-retrieve-formals-of-a-primitive-function